# structure of rails models for restaurant menu edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm developing a website for a restaurant who wants to be able to add, edit and remove menus themselves. I'm using Ruby on Rails and am struggling to find the best way to setup my database models. I want the menu edit page be able to add/edit/delete sections and dishes, using AJAX to update a preview of the menu as sections and dishes are added.

I have gone for a 3 model setup (Menu, Section and Dish). However I am struggling to work out the best way to set them up. I have put the code down below of what I currently have.

```rb
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections
  has_many :dishes, through: :sections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dishes
end
```

```rb
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :dish
end
```

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections
  has_many :menus, through: :sections
end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :menus do
    resources :dishes
  end
  resources :sections
  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

Am I on the right track here or do I need multiple levels of nesting? (the idea of multiple nesting confuses me!)

Comment: This is a great start and I think you're on the right track. Two things come to mind to consider: 1) Will a Dish always be part of a section? Or can a Dish belong directly to a menu? 2) You might not need all 7 actions created by `resources`, so you can limit them with `resource :dishes, only: [:show, :edit]` for example.

Comment: I have few questions on this design.
What are we going to store in the Sections table ? Does the section refers to starters, mains, beverages etc. ? If yes, why not have it as a column in Dishes table ?

Comment: @user2490003 : 1) Yes, a dish will always be part of a section 2) Thanks, I'll remember to change that

Comment: @FaaduBaalak : Yes the sections will be headings for groups of dishes. I thought about using a category column, but thought there may be issues once the client creates multiple menus , and wants to reuse the dishes in other menus, under different sections.
Although I suppose I could force them to resubmit the same dish for this fringe case, if it will mean simplifying the models

Comment: If you are designing only for a restaurant, I don't see the same dish being used in 2 sections then. It will simplify your models greatly.